# Allow browser to use external application to handle certain protocols

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, protocols, handler

It's fairly easy in Mozilla to allow an external program (installed on the clients machine) to handle special protocols (namely the sip protocol) I'm trying to get Chrome and IE at least to open an program which will auto dial the number displayed. I've tried to follow Chrome's "directions" on allowing handlers such as this, but I can't physically add a protocol, and the only link Chrome allows for me is mailto:. Now if I click on the link (presumably for the browser to ask what I would like to do with it, nothing happens). Has anyone had any success in enabling something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this Google Groups](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/ZeNuBIXvKCg) discussion on Disable External Protocol warning.